# what should I do to find the pod evicted reason

Tags: kubernetes

Today when I checked the kubernetes cluster, some of the pod shows the status was evicted. But I only see the evicted status and could not found the detail logs why the pod was evicted. Disk Pressure? CPU pressure? what should I do to found the reason of the pod evicted?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
kubectl describe pod <pod-id> | grep Message
```

This should give you the reason why the pod was evicted. You could also use "less" instead of "grep" to see the whole output. This will show you the limits on the pod among other details.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to look at logs of that particular pod.
Do a describe on that pod and see if you find anything.

> kubectl get pods -o wide
> try the above command to see on which node it was running and run a describe on that node and you find at-least some information related to the eviction.

Answer (score 1):

Eviction is a process where a Pod assigned to a Node is asked for termination. One of the most common cases in Kubernetes is Preemption, where in order to schedule a new Pod in a Node with limited resources, another Pod needs to be terminated to leave resources to the first one.

So, to answer your question, the pod would have got evicted with limited CPU or memory resources allocated.

Comment: I think OP is asking how to find the specific reason for a specific pod.

Comment: "limited CPU or memory" + or "ephemeral storage".